# nsset, core data, correct predicate

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest, nsset

I have "WorkoutList" object in CoreData, which contains field

```
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSSet<Workout *> *workoutList;
```

and have relationship one to many ("Workout" objects). Workout objects contain field named "finish", this is a string. I am trying to get an array of objects in which field "finish" and my string are equal.

```
NSEntityDescription* entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"WorkoutList" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity: entity];

if (dateString)
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"workoutList.finish == %@", dateString];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
}

NSArray* fetchWorkoutList = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

But I can't write correct predicate for that. So my question is what is correct predicate in this example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem was with string in the database it contains a space at the end.

Answer (score 1):

The correct predicate was @"ANY workoutList.finish == %@".